# automatically added <a> tags

Tags: html

I have a weirdest thing, in this peace of code a browser adds  tags automatically. I disabled all javascript and css, left only simple HTML and still see  tags added. Here is my code:

```
             <div id="menu-contact" class="menuNew">
                     <ul class="navi-list">
                            <li class="goto">Go to:</li>
                            <li id="whats"><a href="#menu-welcome">Welcome!</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#menu-about">About</a></li>                    
                            <li><a href="#menu-services">Shop</a></li>                  
                            <li><a class="active" href="#menu-contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul> 
             </div>
```

and here is what firefox4 sees:

```
<div id="menu-contact" class="menuNew">
     <a> </a>
    <ul class="navi-list">
    <a>
       <li class="goto">Go to:</li>
   </a>
      <li id="whats">
    <a></a>
    <a href="#menu-welcome">Welcome!</a>
     </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#menu-about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#menu-services">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a class="active" href="#menu-contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

It basically surrounds each tag by a tag. Again, I removed all js and css references..any idea what's going on?? Funny thing, that I have the same code (with unique IDs) in the same page and it renders normally.. only the last snippet adds  tags..

Comment: Are you able to give the unedited code? I suspect something important is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess absent a link to a live example is that there is a stray `<a>` somewhere above that element, and Firefox is attempting to apply it to all the elements below, and of course not having a very happy time of it. A quick HTML validation will reveal if something like that is going on, since either the `<a>` is unclosed (invalid) or the `<ul>` is inside it (also invalid).

If that doesn't explain it (which is entirely possible, since I'm just speculating wildly), consider crafting a live example we can inspect in detail. Certainly what you're describing is not normal Firefox behavior, so any clues we can get to what makes your situation different will help.

Comment: inspected carefully all elements before this code and found <a/> invalid closing tag... dummy mistake took nearly an hour to figure it out.. Thank you for your brief answer!